# Using cpplint to find typos in variable initialization

Tags: c++, c, cpplint

I want to check my code to find typos like this:

```c
bool check;
check == true; // should be: check = true;
```

This is a valid code in C/C++, so I want to use *cpplint* to find code occurrences of this type.

What *cpplint* configuration should I use?

Comment: You need a linter that checks for rule [MSC12-C](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/MSC12-C.+Detect+and+remove+code+that+has+no+effect+or+is+never+executed) or other rule that says the same thing.

Comment: Do you have you compiler warnings turned on at all? Long before you should look at an external linter, you should use those to catch mistakes. GCC catches that there's something wrong with this with `-Wall`, and Clang and MSVC both see that there's a problem without added options, though Clang with `-Wall` and MSVC give more relevant warnings.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: What compiler do you use? What compiler settings do you use? Enable all compiler warnings. A good compiler should display a warning about a statement without effect or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This typo indeed can be left unnoticed. I'd suggest you not to rely on default compiler configuration.

Assume following code:

```
int main()
{
        int check;
        check == 1;
}
```

When built with `gcc main.c -o main` the compiler will not produce any warnings at all. (Ubuntu 20.04.1, GCC 9.3.0).

However, when built with `gcc main.c -o main -Wall`:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:4:8: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
    4 |  check == 1;
      |  ~~~~~~^~~~
```

You don't need *cpplint* for this kind of typos. That's an overkill.

Comment: Thank you very much :)
I solve that problem!

Answer (score 1):

That code will give me two warnings with my compiler settings, which at e both turned into errors.

One warning is for using the == operator without using the result, the other is for using the uninitialised variable check. And obviously any future use of “check” will give a warning again, until the compiler can proof that check is initialised.